# python code to unify the number of training smples from each category

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, conv-neural-network, classification

I am using Indian Pines (IP) dataset of dimension 145x145x200 for classification problem using DL techniques. I want to train the model by taking equal number of training samples from each category. I am using groupby method but got the error "Must pass 2-d input. shape=(145, 145, 200)".

How would I do it? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from keras.layers import concatenate
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    sample_size = 3

    df = pd.DataFrame(X.tolist(), y)
    balanced_samples = df.groupby('y').apply(lambda x: x.sample(sample_size)).reset_index(drop=True)
    X_balanced = balanced_samples['X']
    y_balanced = balanced_samples['y']
```

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in <cell line: 7>()
> 5 sample_size = 3
> 6
> ----> 7 df = pd.DataFrame(X.tolist(), y)
> 8 balanced_samples = df.groupby('y').apply(lambda x: x.sample(sample_size)).reset_index(drop=True)
> 9 X_balanced = balanced_samples['X']
>
> 5 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/numeric.py
> in _ensure_array(cls, data, dtype, copy)
> 174         if subarr.ndim > 1:
> 175             # GH#13601, GH#20285, GH#27125
> --> 176             raise ValueError("Index data must be 1-dimensional")
> 177
> 178         subarr = np.asarray(subarr)
>
> ValueError: Index data must be 1-dimensional

Comment: what's `df.shape`? i think the problem is the dataframe creation

Comment: Yes, problem is with the dataframe.  I am not able to create dataframe for this dataset.  The shape of X is (145,145,200) and y is (145, 145)

Comment: why use a dataframe at all? dataframes are 2d